404 on site in Wordpress Multisite after migration
I have a Wordpress multisite installation, all my domains (Ionos) target the same IP, everything works fine.
I created a new site on address : https://mymultisite.com/myothersite
I dont't own the domain "myothersite.com", but the ping gives me the good IP adress (same as other sites). I changed the address in my worpress site configuration for myothsite.com
I cannot access the site (404 nginx), with or without https. When changing again the address for https://mymultisite.com/myothersite everything is OK.
Here is the content of my .htaccess :
# BEGIN WordPress Multisite

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress Multisite

Does someone have an idea ?
Thanks in advance

You need to create the myothsite.com domain on your ionos admin, link it to the wp directory and create the https certificate
